# How to get information from the currently clicked marker in gmaps4rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

I am trying to find a way to get information from the currently clicked marker on a map. For example, I would like to show the title and description of the currently clicked marker to show up on a different page. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a listener on click:

```
var handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap({ provider: { }, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
  // I assume this is the way you retrieve the amrkers array
  var json_data = <%=raw @hash.to_json %>;
  var markers = handler.addMarkers(json_data);

  _.each(json_data, function(json, index){
    var marker  = markers[index];
    json.marker = marker;
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker.getServiceObject(), 'click', function(){
      console.log(json);
      //whatever you need here
    });
  });

});
```

Comment: thank you for this. this answers my questions i wish i had enough rep to upvote :(